# Grails / RenderPdf Arabic Chars

Tags: pdf, grails, render, arabic

We have a grails app, in which we are using the [Render Plugin](http://gpc.github.com/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/index.html) to render content in .pdf. It all works fine for English, but unfortunately for Arabic (which we must render) all the charactes seem "broken". Some numbers and spaces there...

The render plugin uses IText, and I have tried the approach with:

```
...  
def renderer = new ITextRenderer()  
FontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver()  
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-arabeyes/ae_AlArabiya.ttf", BaseFont.EMBEDDED)  
...
```

(the font used here is just an example), but in any case, it doesn't work.

Anybody any experience with this kind of issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
renderer.getFontResolver.addFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED_SUBSET);
```

The default encoding for fonts in iText is WinAnsiEncoding, AKA Code Page 1252.  You need to specify an encoding that contains the characters you want...

Yep.  Google Code produced this bit of code for the addFont you're using:

```
public void addFont(String path, boolean embedded)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
    addFont(path, BaseFont.CP1252, embedded);
}
```

IDENTITY_H lets you address all the glyphs in a given font.  I always recommend it, though there is a small drawback.  Using IDENTITY_H forces the font to be an embedded subset in iText, no way around it.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response. Eventually we bypassed the .pdf creation for the time being, but I will certainly give your suggestion a try once I get my hands on the Arabic .pdf again.