# How do I get the CSS fonts to work with this Grails PDF rendering plug-in?

Tags: css, grails, pdf-generation, rendering, gsp

I am using a Grails rendering plugin to generate PDF.

I want to include CSS with my PDF to render it nicely.  I found an example on the [rendering plugin website](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/single.html)

I put the CSS below in print media so that it works for PDF, but this does not work for me. I also do not know how to change the font from Arial to another font.  Can someone explain this to me?

The plugin uses Arial font with this CSS:

```css
@font-face {
  src: url(path/to/arial.ttf);
  -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
  -fs-pdf-font-encoding: cp1250;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need arialuni.ttf not just arial.ttf download it here: http://www.findthatfonts.com/search-2683324-hTTF/fonts-download-search-engine-ARIALUNI.ttf.htm

Then

You have to give your @font-face a font-family name like this:

```css
@font-face {
font-family: "Font-Name";
  src: url(path/to/font.ttf); // you have to add your font.ttf file to the server in a folder like assets/css/fonts or something.
  -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
  -fs-pdf-font-encoding: cp1250;
}

body {
  font-family: "Font-Name", Arial, sans-serif; // you called your font Font-Name in the @font-face so now you can use it as Font-Name everywhere else in you css.
}
```

Otherwise your arialuni.ttf has no name so you can't use it in other divs in your css.

Comment: Thanks for reply.You are only talking about a particular font thats arial, I need some general solution that can apply on any imported font in css.

Comment: Doesn't matter you can change the fontname. the url has to have the exact same name as the font on your server. the Font-Family name can be different.

Comment: I tried same thing before. Its working fine when I open my template on browser, but it do not work when I download my gsp template as pdf.

Comment: No if you download the template as pdf the font is not working anymore because it was on your server. When downloaded the font isn't in reach anymore because you are working locally then.

Comment: So any idea that I can put my own font in pdf?

Comment: You need to embed your font in pdf using php http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-findfont.php

Comment: I am working on grails and using rendering plugin to generate pdf. How can I use php code in grails.

Comment: Maybe this works. It's not exactly the same but it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366990/grails-renderpdf-arabic-chars

Comment: Thanks for providing me link... But I am not getting what I exactly want.

Comment: I never used grails and those plugins so I can't help you with this. I used googled that link. But if my answer was helpful anyway consider to accept it. you can open a new question with the problem you are getting now.

Answer (score 1):

The next is working for me good:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Calibri';
   src: url(${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/fonts/calibri.ttf);
   -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
   -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}
```

The `-fs-pdf-font-encoding` should be set in `Identity-H`.
And after it you can add something like

```
 body {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
 }
```

Comment: Do you use it with rendering plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter what name you give the font, as long as you choose a name for the src you provide between te @font-face brackets, like `font-family: "SomeName";`. 
Now, you can use the font everywhere using `font-family: "SomeName"`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried same thing before. Its working fine when I open my template on browser, but it do not work when I try to download  my template as pdf.