# Grails, rendering plugin removes exotic characters

Tags: pdf, grails, fonts, rendering, gsp

I want the plugin to create pdf-files and that works well when you only use standard characters but if you want special polish characters they don't show up. For example: "Wartość" will be "Warto".
I found the following recommendation:

```
<style>
@font-face {
      src: url(path/to/arial.ttf);
      -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
      -fs-pdf-font-encoding: cp1250;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

But how can I make this work? url(path/to/arial.ttf) How do I do that, cant find any .ttf-file on WIN10 and how can I make it work on a deployment?

If I try to use any font on C:\windows\Font\ I get Null pointer exception. Probably b'cause there is no file with that name or path wrongly expressed.
Please help, I thought it should be a simple thing to create a polish version of a report but this became a disaster.

Comment: Any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859152/how-do-i-get-the-css-fonts-to-work-with-this-grails-pdf-rendering-plug-in

Comment: Well, as I understand of that conversation, it doesn't work in your downloaded pdf as the pdf will not contain the font. I have got the problem solved as the customer was satisfied without those extra signs on the letters. But I still believe that it should be possible in some way t o   have that font included in the pdf.